# Getting error in my constructor

Tags: java

In my class assignment I need to create a constructor for Matrix, and im getting an error i'm not familiar with...

this is the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Method breakpoint:Matrix [entry] - Matrix(int, 
     int)
    - Syntax error on token "public", delete this 
     token
```

And this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {

    private int [][] data;
    private Scanner 

    // Class constructor - can be created only when a user provide positive columns and rows
    public Matrix(int r, int c) throws DidNotProvideMatrixData
    {
        if (r <= 0 || c <= 0) {
            throw new DidNotProvideMatrixData("Rows and Columns have to be positive!");
        } else {
            this.data = new int[r][c];
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is this ? `private Scanner` There is no variable's name and no semi-colon.

Comment: @ZouZou, that is correct, and it should be an answer, not a comment.  Actually, it WAS an answer; I'm not sure why the respondent deleted it.

Comment: @DavidWallace There is a close reason for typographical errors, so I closed as it. The answerer changed it after my comment, he first stated that the OP should remove `public` in `public Matrix` (hence my comment)

Comment: Ive deleted it because i got a vote down even if it's correct. The Creator wrote that it's already a "comment".

Comment: @ZouZou it's because i stop in the middle for something and forgot to complete it...there is no reason to downvote so much

Comment: @SQS I didn't downvote your question btw. I no longer give downvotes.

Comment: You can always edit your question.

Comment: @ZouZou I have no issue with the question being downvoted and/or closed.  I was just confused as to why the correct answer had been deleted; and I strongly disagree with the person who said that the answer should have been a comment.  Deleting an answer after a single downvote and one negative comment seems like an extreme reaction.  In any case, I'm glad that the answer has been reinstated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

private Scanner?
You are missing a varname and a ;

after fixing this it should compile just fine.

Comment: No this is the constructor, so `public` is fine.

Comment: thanks Emanuel, this fixed the prob, it was a stupid mistype, I will approve the answer shortly since i still cant :) @Emanuel Seibold